# How to skew an image from left bottom to top?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to skew an image as shown below but so far, I have gotten to work the opposite way. I've tried various skew positions but unable to get it.

I want the skew to work like this as shown in the image:

[image]

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/vpqytn53/

**My code:**

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.box div {
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box div img {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: inherit;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1069/300/200.jpg?hmac=senkn1L_edHHUsRFhKqx15UOq2Ci-2656EDeaRgumNw">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: see the clip-path method from the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif I checked but the shake I want doesn't exist in `Method 3 - Skew Transforms`. Using that code base, I couldn't get the shape.

Comment: Check out [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/), that can generate the shape you want.

Comment: Do you actually want the image skewsed or do you just want a slope as the left side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you will need to change the `transform-origin` property of `.box div` from:

```
.box div {
  transform-origin: top; /* read: top left */
}
```

to:

```
.box div {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.box div {
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box div img {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: inherit;
  transform:skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1069/300/200.jpg?hmac=senkn1L_edHHUsRFhKqx15UOq2Ci-2656EDeaRgumNw">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying every value and messing up everything.